# getting a worklist and saving it to a file

Tags: java, saving-data, dcm4che

I'm trying to retrieve the work list from the pacs server and saving it to a file "worklist.properties". I'm working on this code:

```
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import org.dcm4che2.data.BasicDicomObject;
    import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomElement;
    import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject;
    import org.dcm4che2.data.SpecificCharacterSet;
    import org.dcm4che2.data.Tag;
    import org.dcm4che2.data.UID;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.Association;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.CommandUtils;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.Device;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.DimseRSP;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.NetworkApplicationEntity;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.NetworkConnection;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.NewThreadExecutor;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.NoPresentationContextException;
    import org.dcm4che2.net.TransferCapability;

    public class TestGetMwl {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args/*,String aet, String host, Integer port*/) {
            new TestGetMwl(/*aet,host,port*/);
        }

        private static final int[] RETURN_KEYS = {
            Tag.AccessionNumber,
            Tag.ReferringPhysicianName,
            Tag.PatientName,
            Tag.PatientID,
            Tag.PatientBirthDate,
            Tag.PatientSex,
            Tag.PatientWeight,
            Tag.MedicalAlerts,
            Tag.Allergies,
            Tag.PregnancyStatus,
            Tag.StudyInstanceUID,
            Tag.RequestingPhysician,
            Tag.RequestingService,
            Tag.RequestedProcedureDescription,
            Tag.AdmissionID,
            Tag.SpecialNeeds,
            Tag.CurrentPatientLocation,
            Tag.PatientState,
            Tag.RequestedProcedureID,
            Tag.RequestedProcedurePriority,
            Tag.PatientTransportArrangements,
            Tag.PlacerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest,
            Tag.FillerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest,
            Tag.ConfidentialityConstraintOnPatientDataDescription,
        };

        private static final int[] SPS_RETURN_KEYS = {
            Tag.Modality,
            Tag.RequestedContrastAgent,
            Tag.ScheduledStationAETitle,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime,
            Tag.ScheduledPerformingPhysicianName,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepDescription,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepID,
            Tag.ScheduledStationName,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepLocation,
            Tag.PreMedication,
            Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStatus
        };

        private static final String[] LE_TS = {
            UID.ExplicitVRLittleEndian, 
            UID.ImplicitVRLittleEndian };

        private static final byte[] EXT_NEG_INFO_FUZZY_MATCHING = { 1, 1, 1 };

        private Device device;
        private final NetworkApplicationEntity remoteAE = new NetworkApplicationEntity();
        private final NetworkConnection remoteConn = new NetworkConnection();
         private final NetworkApplicationEntity ae = new NetworkApplicationEntity();
         private final NetworkConnection conn = new NetworkConnection();
         private final DicomObject keys = new BasicDicomObject();
         private final DicomObject spsKeys = new BasicDicomObject();
         private Association assoc;
         private int priority = 0;
         private int cancelAfter = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//ÐœÐ°ÐºÑ ÐºÐ¾Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡ÐµÑÑ‚Ð²Ð¾ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾Ðº

         private boolean fuzzySemanticPersonNameMatching;

        public TestGetMwl(/*String aet, String host, Integer port*/) {
            String name = "DCMMWL";
            device = new Device(name);
            NewThreadExecutor executor = new NewThreadExecutor(name);
            remoteAE.setInstalled(true);
            remoteAE.setAssociationAcceptor(true);
            remoteAE.setNetworkConnection(new NetworkConnection[] { remoteConn });

            device.setNetworkApplicationEntity(ae);
            device.setNetworkConnection(conn);
            ae.setNetworkConnection(conn);
            ae.setAssociationInitiator(true);
            ae.setAETitle(name);
            for (int i = 0; i < RETURN_KEYS.length; i++) {
                keys.putNull(RETURN_KEYS[i], null);
            }        
            keys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.RequestedProcedureCodeSequence,
                    new BasicDicomObject());
            keys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepSequence, spsKeys);
            for (int i = 0; i < SPS_RETURN_KEYS.length; i++) {
                spsKeys.putNull(SPS_RETURN_KEYS[i], null);
            }
            spsKeys.putNestedDicomObject(Tag.ScheduledProtocolCodeSequence,
                    new BasicDicomObject());

            /////////
           // remoteAE.setAETitle(aet);
           // remoteConn.setHostname(host);
           // remoteConn.setPort(port);
            remoteAE.setAETitle("DCM4CHEE");
            remoteConn.setHostname("localhost");
            remoteConn.setPort(11112);

           // addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.Modality, "CR");
            //addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.Modality, "CR");
    //        addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate,"20131030");
    //        addSpsMatchingKey(Tag.ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime,"11111");

            setTransferSyntax(LE_TS);

            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                assoc = ae.connect(remoteAE, executor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: Failed to establish association:");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.exit(2);
            }

            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Connected to " + remoteAE + " in "
                    + ((t2 - t1) / 1000F) + "s");

            try {
                List<DicomObject> result = query();
                long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                System.out.println("Received " + result.size()
                        + " matching entries in " + ((t3 - t2) / 1000F) + "s");

                for(DicomObject dcm : result) {
     //             DicomElement pn = dcm.get(Tag.PatientName);



            Properties worklist = new Properties();
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {

                output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\properties\\worklist.properties");

                // set the properties value
                worklist.setProperty("1",dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));
                worklist.setProperty("2",dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));


                // save properties to project root folder
                worklist.store(output, null);

            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
              System.out.println("!!! PatientName="+dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));

               // }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                assoc.release(true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Released connection to " + remoteAE);

            }
        public void setTransferSyntax(String[] ts) {
            TransferCapability tc = new TransferCapability(
                    UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND, ts,
                    TransferCapability.SCU);
            if (fuzzySemanticPersonNameMatching)
                tc.setExtInfo(EXT_NEG_INFO_FUZZY_MATCHING);
            ae.setTransferCapability(new TransferCapability[]{tc});
        }

            public void addSpsMatchingKey(int tag, String value) {
            spsKeys.putString(tag, null, value);
        }

        public List<DicomObject> query() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            TransferCapability tc = assoc.getTransferCapabilityAsSCU(
                    UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND);
            if (tc == null) {
                throw new NoPresentationContextException(
                        "Modality Worklist not supported by "
                        + remoteAE.getAETitle());
            }
            //System.out.println("Send Query Request:");
            //System.out.println(keys.toString());
            DimseRSP rsp = assoc.cfind(UID.ModalityWorklistInformationModelFIND,
                    priority, keys, tc.getTransferSyntax()[0], cancelAfter);
            List<DicomObject> result = new ArrayList<DicomObject>();
            while (rsp.next()) {
                DicomObject cmd = rsp.getCommand();
                if (CommandUtils.isPending(cmd)) {
                    DicomObject data = rsp.getDataset();
                    result.add(data);
                    //System.out.println("\nReceived Query Response #"
                          //  + result.size() + ":");
                    //System.out.println(data.toString());
                }
            }
            return result;

        }
}
```

when my worklist containes just one element it works perfectly. But, when the worklist containes more than one element, I get as a result just the last element saved in the worklist file.
please any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Perhaps it is because in your loop " for(DicomObject dcm : result) {" you open the file output stream "output" and write the new worklist properties object - which in turn is overwriting your earlier results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks your code has got following problems:
Firstly,

```
output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\properties\\worklist.properties");
```

is inside for loop

```
for(DicomObject dcm : result) {
```

-> the worklist.properties file will be overwritten again and again.

The second,

```
worklist.setProperty("1",dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));
worklist.setProperty("2",dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));
```

got same property keys (**1** and **2**) so the value will be overwritten too.

**EDIT:**
 Add sample code:

```
output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\properties\\worklist.properties");
// For example
int propid = 1;
for(DicomObject dcm : result) {
    String key = "patientName" + new Integer(propid++).toString();
    worklist.setProperty(key,dcm.getString(Tag.PatientName));
}
worklist.store(output, null);
```

Comment: if I have more than one element in the worklist how should I set the properties automatically ?

Comment: You should create unique key for each data. I edited answer in order to adding sample code.

Comment: What if I want to work with a clickable rows table instead of saving the liste to a file. In other words, a new window opened showing the worklist elements in the forme of a table as each element of the worklist has many attributes and it allows me to select the element(the whole row by double mouse clicking) I want to work with.I'm so sorry to be demanding but I'm very new to java .

Comment: In that case, may be you have to use SWING for dealing with GUI. The following example should be helpful  **[simple table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple)**